# Problema tratando de ordenar un vector de cadenas que hereda de Vector<String>

Tags: java, array, string

tengo una clase `VecCadenas` que hereda de `Vector<String>`:

```
public class VecCadenas extends Vector<String>
```

Quiero ordenar el vector (el cual se arma en el constructor desde un archivo de texto linea a linea), puedo verificar en mi Main que el objeto VecCadenas en efecto se arma:

```
VecCadenas v = new VecCadenas("miarchivo1.txt");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El # de cadenas en el vector creado es: " +v.size());
```

Ahora, dentro la misma clase `VecCadenas` tengo un método para ordenarlo:

```
public void ordenar () {
    for (int i=0;i<size();i++){
        for (int j=0; j<size(); j++){
            if ( (this.elementAt(i).compareToIgnoreCase(elementAt(j))) < 0){
                String aux = elementAt(i);
                String aux2 = elementAt(j);
                insertElementAt(aux,j);
                insertElementAt(aux2,i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando llamo este  método en mi Main:

```
v.ordenar();
```

mi programa se cuelga en memoria por lo visto, alguien puede ayudarme a saber que esta pasando?

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La cosa es que `java.util.Vector` implementa `java.util.List`, entonces no hay necesidad de escribir un nuevo método para ordenar tu vector. Puedes utilizar [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) para ese propósito.

Por ejemplo:

```
Vector<String> jedi = new Vector<>();
jedi.add("Yoda");
jedi.add("Luke");
jedi.add("Mace-Windu");
jedi.add("Obi-Wan");

Collections.sort(jedi, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
System.out.println(jedi);
```

Este código produce un vector ordenado: `[Luke, Mace-Windu, Obi-Wan, Yoda]`

Si estas usando Java 8 o superior, incluso puedes invocar el método [List.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-), p.ej.

```
jedi.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```

Produciría el mismo resultado que `Collections.sort`.

Ahora bien, respecto de tu programa para ordenar, pienso que el problema es que estas intentando usar [insertElementAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#insertElementAt-E-int-), cuando en realidad lo que deseas es hacer un reset del elemento. Para eso puedes usar [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#set-int-E-).

De hecho que si cambio tu programa para usar `set`, funciona bien:

```
public static void ordenar (Vector<String> items) {
        for (int i=0; i < items.size(); i++){
            for (int j=0; j < items.size(); j++){
                if ( (items.elementAt(i).compareToIgnoreCase(items.elementAt(j))) < 0) {
                    String aux = items.elementAt(i);
                    String aux2 = items.elementAt(j);
                    items.set(j, aux);
                    items.set(i, aux2);
                }
            }
    }
```

Si lo llamo con `ordenar(jedi)` produce el resultado esperado: `[Luke, Mace-Windu, Obi-Wan, Yoda]`.

Podrás inferir la razón por la cual tu programa se cuelga para siempre si lees la documentación de [insertElementAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#insertElementAt-E-int-):

> Each component in this vector with an index greater or equal to the specified index is shifted upward to have an index one greater than the value it had previously

Que traducido es algo como:

> Cada componente de este vector con un índice mayor o igual al índice especificado se moverá hacia arriba, para tener un índice cuyo valor es mayor en uno al valor del índice que tenía previamente.

Eso quiere decir que cada vez que realizas esa operación en realidad le estas agregando más elementos el vector, en vez de intercambiarlos (como esperabas que ocurriera). Como tu algoritmo itera hasta el tamaño del vector, pues nunca llega a su final, porque en cada iteración haces el vector más grande.

De hecho que esto es fácil de demostrar, todo lo que tenemos que hacer es modificar tu programa para que en vez de preguntar por el tamaño del vector en cada iteración, solo lo pregunta una vez antes de entrar al bucle.

```
 public static void ordenar (Vector<String> items) {
        int size = items.size();
        for (int i=0; i < size; i++){
            for (int j=0; j < size; j++){
                if ( (items.elementAt(i).compareToIgnoreCase(items.elementAt(j))) < 0) {
                    String aux = items.elementAt(i);
                    String aux2 = items.elementAt(j);
                    items.insertElementAt(aux, j);
                    items.insertElementAt(aux2, i);
                }
            }
    }
```

Y al invocar esta version modificada con la lista de `jedi` podrás ver como se agregaron varios elementos adicionales a la colección, produciendo el resultado: `[Luke, Luke, Yoda, Yoda, Yoda, Luke, Mace-Windu, Obi-Wan]`.

Eso hace más claro como se producen las duplicaciones en tu algoritmo original.

Comment: Gracias por la excelente y completa respuesta Edwin, ya había pillado porque se colgaba ya que los limites se movían y restringí capturando el tamaño en el Main y pasándoselo, no obstante hacia cosas raras con el vector y ya se porque es y gracias a tu respuesta!!

Comment: @NandoSevilla Si te pareció bien mi respuesta considera votar por ella y marcarla como la respuesta a tu pregunta para que contribuyas a mi reputación en el sitio.